# EOS mainnet replay speed too slow after about 20M blocks

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code, block-producer, mainnet

while replay the node sync speed was fast in start but after about syncing 20M blocks the speed is very very slow.

> mongoDb and history plugins are enabled.

nodeos is not utilizing above 1500 iops while the server iops limit is above 20k.

server specs:

- **CPU:** Intel Xeon 3.2Ghz * 8.
- **RAM:** 32GB
- **SSD:** 1TB
- **IOPS:** ~20000

server `iostats`:

[image]

> any suggestions on how i can boost the replay.?